# How to change the style of a few echoed pieces of text?

Tags: php, css

```
<?php
$blacklist = array("no.html", "one.php");

if ($handle = opendir('.')) {

    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

        if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
            echo "<a href='$entry'><li id='file'>$entry\n</li></a>";
        }

    }

    closedir($handle);
}

?>
```

What happens here is that every file in the directory (excluding those in the blacklist) get echoed out like so:

- 1.html
- 2.html
- 3.html
- 4.html
- 5.html
- 6.html
- 7.html
- 8.html

However, is there any way to style certain elements? For example, every 3 echo's, make the text bigger and the color red.

E.g.

- 1.html
- 2.html
- **3.html**
- 4.html
- 5.html
- **6.html**
- 7.html
- 8.html

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I think it will help you

```
    $i = 1;
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {

     if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
       if($i%3 == 0){
         echo "<a href='$entry'><strong><li id='file'>$entry</li></strong></a>";
       }else{
         echo "<a href='$entry'><li id='file'>$entry</li></a>";
       }
    }
    $i++;

  }
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there any way to add something that's not included in the echo? For example, an image after the 5th echo which doesn't appear again after that?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this with the counter initialized will do the job.

```
while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
    if ($entry != "." && $entry != ".." &&  !in_array($entry, $blacklist)) {
        if ($i%3==0)
        {
            //the echo with the style
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<a href='$entry'><li id='file'>$entry\n</li></a>";
        }       
    }
    $i++
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also, is there any way to add something that's not included in the echo? For example, an image after the 5th echo which doesn't appear again after that?

Comment: Yes you can add an "else if ($i == 5)" or $i whatever you want and in there to present anything.